# .net core tables doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My problem is: I have project with authorization and authentication. I've added few models (Article, Category), repos and irepos for these. Database shows only tables created by identity framework. There is lack of my own! I've done migration and updated database. Below screen from SQL SOE
[image]

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddTransient<IArticleRepository, ArticleRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
    }
```

DBcontext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Blog.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Blog.Data
{
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Article> Articles;
    public DbSet<Category> Categories;
    public DbSet<IdentityUser> Users;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasData(new Article { Id=1, CategoryId=1, Content="cont", Title="title" });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Quite often this is because the database isn't where you expect to see it. If you've run migrations, they should be in the migrations table? Can you show information about where you expect the database to be (from your EF setup), and what you're looking at in 'SQL SOE' (whatever that might be!)

Comment: @stuartd Yeah - BlogDb (as on the screen) is my database. My tables (Categories, Articles) should be in "one line" with UserIdentities. SQL SOE - SQL Server Object Explorer.

Comment: @stuartd BTW: How can i check my EF setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted Database and all migrations. Added

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

After migration and update - works.